# Azure: Pricing of event hubs

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

I'm trying to work with the pricing calculator for event hubs: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/?service=service-bus .

Unfortunately, where it says "Ingress" it only says "Million events". It doesn't say "per hour", "per day" or "per month". Does anyone know?

I've got three billion events per month and can't enter it becaus the field only allows me to enter 999 million events.

Lots of Greetings!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to pricing calculator limitations, you cannot exceed more than 999. You can do manual calculation according to your requirement as mentioned below.

**Note:** Ingress events are calculated **€0.024** per million events.

For three billion events it will be 3000 million is approximately €0.024x3000= €72 + through put.

An ingress event is a unit of data 64 KB or less. Each one is a billable event. Larger messages are billed in multiples of 64 KB. For example, 8 KB is billed as one event, but a 96 KB message is billed as two events.

Events consumed from an event hub, as well as management operations and "control calls" such as checkpoints, are not counted as billable ingress events, but accrue to the throughput unit allowance.

For more details, refer “[Event Hub pricing](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/details/event-hubs/) and [Event Hub Pricing FAQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-faq#pricing)”.

Comment: So, it's events per month then?

Comment: Ok, checked with support: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/77e2d09e-6093-4611-82a2-0ade93aa9db6/event-hub-ingress-pricing-unclear . It's indeed per month.

Comment: If we select a higher TU for min TU in Standard pricing, suppose 20 TU, and do not use then how the charges will be applied? Will 20 TU be considered for cost or whatever is used?